# What antipattern does this common programming mistake fall under

Tags: naming-conventions, terminology, anti-patterns

For a programming project,

let's say the programmer has named similar style functions differently in many places, for example...

```
int ask_bro_4_data();
```

and another as

```
int ask_mom_for_data();
```

What antipattern does this represent? Essentially, it's the lack of standardization right? As in, one function uses for, the other uses 4.

Similarily the programmer could be naming variables in some fashion that relates to their use but fails to do so in every case, or does so in a non standardized way. This makes searching for these variables in a large code base harder because they may not be following the naming condition that you assume they would be.

Any ideas? Sorry for the ambiguous name, but I was not sure what to label this question as.

Comment: I don't think it's an anti-pattern at all. An anti-pattern initially seems like a good idea; I don't think anybody would actually look at this, think about it for even a second, and consider it a good idea. To me it looks like simple lack of thought/consideration.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think it is an anti[attern. The initial good idea == "Well let's just get this written as soon as possible and worry about naming conventions later. No need to look for how I wrote it earlier, just keep trudging along"  It is an organizational or management anti-pattern

Comment: I'm still left disagreeing. Even looking at management, I doubt anybody looked at this and thought it was a good idea. From what I've seen it's usually that they decided it was the least of the available evils, or else just failed to consider the consequences of their decisions. If you really insist on dignifying it as an "anti-pattern", the proper title would probably be "shortsightedness".

Comment: @JerryCoffin The good idea isn't to not have naming conventions. The "good idea" is lets rush this out the door as soon as possible, we need to get it to market quick" . The naming convention problem, among other things, are the negative effects of that managerial antipattern. Apologies for wording the question oddly...

Comment: I'm agree that this is not antipattern. against coding standard, yes. but definitelly not antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

This would be considered more a syntax convention than a pattern.

The English language would lead us to prescribe using words in preference to numerals in order to improve maintainability. However, conventions can vary significantly depending on your peer group.

A design pattern would be considered a solution intended to address common problems introduced by a specific context.

For example; I want to ensure my application can only ever access the same instance of a given class. A basic pattern to address this problem would be the Singleton.

If the solution then introduces more problems than it solves; then it becomes an anti-pattern.

In this example; Singletons are hard to unit test; so this is one reason why many consider it an anti-pattern.

Comment: Singletons are an anti-pattern

Comment: Yes, but it is still an organizational/management anti-pattern in that the programmer decided the solution for the system was to complete it as quickly as possible and get it out the door, instead of focussing on standardization of naming conventions. Basically, it falls under the umbrella of code-rush poor management.

Comment: or, at least, it is the negative effect of an antipattern. I do not know what that antipattern is called.

Comment: Naming is too subjective to be called a pattern (or anti). A pattern implies a reusable solution which can only exist if there is an easily defined problem in the first place.

Comment: @PaulFerguson I'm sorry, my question was worded improperly, but if you read my comment I give a much clearer indication of what I am talking about. the Antipattern is the thought process that shipping it is more important than maintanence, and is an antipattern because those who are managing the system in the future need to play catchup and stumble through these sort of inconsistencies and badly documented code to get an understanding of the system, when it would be vastly easier and quicker if it was documented and standardized to begin with

Answer (score 0):

### Anti-Pattern: *Rename later*

When the programmer realize that he/she or her collegues are inconsistent in naming and decide to do something about it later, or that is not important to do something about at all.

This can be coped with by:

- clear **guidelines** from the team about what to strive for in respecting naming conventions,
- recognizing that refactoring is an **ongoing process**, parallel to the coding.
- **simple IDE commands** that afford the user after thinking *oh we used "4" here and "for" here, that's disturbing* *Ctrl+R Ctrl+R* *ah that's better* *continues coding.*